# MySQL truncating restricted, but can delete row?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Not entirely sure but I think there may be a MySQL bug.

I have three tables:

`TimesheetEntries` (A timesheet entry is related to a timesheet)
`Timesheets_Users` (The relationship between timesheets and users)
`Timesheets`

I created a foreign key *(RESTRICT on DELETE)* on both `TimesheetEntries` and `Timesheets_Users` to say:

"Don't allow someone to delete the timesheet if there is a `TimesheetEntry` or `Timesheets_Users` relationship that exists"

Cool, so i go and create a timesheet with 1 timesheet entry. I'm really happy to see that the result is:

1 row created in `TimesheetEntries`, it relates correctly to the...
1 row created in `Timesheets`.
1 row created in `Timesheets_Users`, it relates correctly to a User (in another table we don't care about)

So, if I go and try to truncate (delete contents) of the `Timesheets` table, it should and does restrict me from doing it.. Cool it works!

I then decide to truncate `TimesheetEntries` and `Timesheets_Users` tables. All cool still... it emptied them correctly.

Now, you'd be thinking, `Timesheets` **should now** allow me to truncate it? **It doesn't?** Okay fine, so I may have perhaps done something wrong, but it should at least mean that if I try to delete the `Timesheets` row rather than truncating it, it should also restrict me.

**BUT IT DOESN'T?**

A very odd occurrence, I think it's a bug...
Am I missing something?

Comment: My colleague has just explained that the TRUNCATE operates on mass... and does not check row specific relations. This would explain that shizbadizzle... however, without a delete all button in PHPMyAdmin, it's a real dong basher... coz you have to check all, over and over until you delete, or run a sql command yourself. Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: just confirm if timesheet is a child table in your case.

Comment: Timesheets holds TimesheetEntries... Thus, TimesheetEntries relate to a Timesheet. I would, in this case, say Timesheets is a parent table, it's children (TimesheetEntries) relate to it.

Comment: insert one entry in timesheets table and also insert its one chile entry in its child table then try to delete this new entry from timesheets table..as per my understanding if there is no corresponding child entry in child table then mysql allow you to delete row from master other wise not but mysql will not allow truncate in any condition as it works on schema level so it is not allowed if there is a relationship.

Comment: I'll spend more time on this thread when I get home...

Comment: Please post your exact DDL and DML statements, I am convinced the foreign keys are defined incorrectly.